# Does using Firebase Authentication in Flutter app with Firestore usage always required?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

Do you still need to use Firebase Authentication when using Firestore in a Flutter app? The reason I'm asking is that I believe you have to use `request` when setting up Firestore rules."

"I personally think that way, but I would like to hear your opinions. Please share your thoughts

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54083375/setting-firestore-security-rules-without-using-firebase-authentication

Answer (score 0):

It is not required.  Just know that without Firebase Auth, you won't be able to enforce per-user access.  Your security rules will have to be extremely permissive, where everyone has all the same access to all same documents.

Whether or not you should choose this situation is a matter of opinion an entirely up to you.  You have to decide if this meets your app's requirements for security.

Comment: I understand that it depends on each case.
Do you think it's possible to set secure firestore rules without using `request`?

Comment: As I said already: "You have to decide if this meets your app's requirements for security."  I can't tell you what "secure" means for your app.